# Calling an integer to a method cast in a private void

Tags: android, methods, integer, call

I am in a single class, using 2 different methods.

In one method I have:

```
private void detect();
    int facesFound = detector.findFaces(bitmap565, faces);
```

detector, bitmap565 and faces are all defined in the same method.

In another method, I would like to call the value of facesFound.

So:

```
private void crop(){
if (facesFound > 1){

}
```

My issue is, I cannot access that integer from the method because it is cast locally.  What is my best way to alter my code to call it?

Edit: to add method:

```
private final View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
   case R.id.action_button:
        crop();
```

So are you saying declare an integer at the top of my class that is defined as getting the integer passed back through my new private int detect() method?

Comment: Would it be logical to have `facesFound` be a member variable, and you would set it via `detect`?

Comment: +1, I agree. That would be the logical choice.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?  Sorry I am quite new to this.

Comment: I think you mean that facesFound is declared locally not "cast locally".

Comment: right, it is an integer declared inside my detect(); method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `detect()` and `crop()` to:

```
private int detect()
{
    return detector.findFaces(bitmap565, faces);
}

private void crop(int numberOfFacesFound)
{
    if(numberOfFacesFound > 1)
    {

    }
}
```

Then, wherever you are calling `crop()` from:

```
int numberOfFacesFound = detect();
crop(numberOfFacesFound);
```

Comment: what if I am calling crop in a separate private method as an onClickListener with switch statements?

Comment: Thats where you would put the call to `detect()`. If you can't do that for some reason, you could declare a private field in the class to hold the value returned by `detect()` which you could then pass to `crop(int)`.

Comment: edited in my private button method...still not getting your comment, but I certainly get your answer ;)